# Newton's Method to find point on function closest to origin

Tags: calculus

Using Newton's Method, find the coordinates accurate to 6 decimal points of the point on the function y=e^x that is closest to the origin.

Comment: Newton's Method looks for the zeros of a function.  You might start telling us about your attempts to write down that function.

Comment: @avs There is a Newton's method for finding the zeros of a function, and also a Newton's method for minimizing a smooth function $f$.  (The second Newton's method works by using the first Newton's method to solve $\nabla f(x) = 0$.)

Comment: @littleO, yes, so, essentially, there is only one Newton's method.:)  And I was trying to encourage ConMan to write down the suitable $f$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

We want the $x$ that yields the minimum value of $D(x)$, the *distance* between $(0,0)$ and $(x, e^x)$. This is the value for which $D'(x)=0$ and $D''(x)>0$.

Here we would approximate $D'(x) = 0$ using Newton's Method as given by: $$ x_{n + 1} = x_n - \frac{D'(x_n)}{D''(x_n)} $$

Now we just need an expression for $D(x)$ and a first approximation, $x_1$.

Comment: Should be fixed now @user251257

Answer (score 1):

The squared distance of $(x,e^x)$ from the origin is given by $x^2+e^{2x}$, whose derivative is given by $2x+2e^{2x}$. It follows that the minimal distance is achieved at the only real root of $e^{2x}+x$ (that is a convex function). By choosing $x_0=0$ as starting point, Newton's method
$$ x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{e^{2x_n}+x_n}{2e^{2x_n}+1} $$
gives $x\approx -0.426303$ with just $4$ iterations. The minimal distance is so $\approx\color{red}{0.779767}$.
Here we have $x=-\frac{1}{2}W(2)$ where $W$ is [Lambert's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score -1):

Newton's Method will approximate the solution of $ f(x) = 0 $.
Draw a diagram, consider your function, and apply the formula: $$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} $$ until you get your answer